# Angular 5 - Create a library project

Tags: angular, angular5

I've two angular apps built on Angular 5 (take a look on dep. modules below)

```
    (...)
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.11"
     (...)
```

I want to create a library or some sort of shared module that can be put in a separated folder to be used on the two apps. 
I can't find any examples for creating libraries on Angular 5 because as far I know It's a features of Angular 6+ CLI. 
How can I manually create a common lib for my two projects?

Answer (score -1):

You can do both options; shared module is the easier but no the better.

Develop a custom library with CLI:

```
ng g library custom-lib
```

generates all the resources that you will need but then you have to set the appropiate config. Some of them:

`package.json` in library: you set the library version and dependencies

`package.json` in module: you set the routes for build, test and pack (this will generate the .tgz file wich you can publish via nexus **advanced**)

`imported.json`, `include.json` or `public-api.ts` are also important files to define wich components, services, etc will be exported and shared and where be imported in the app **advanced**

Developing and Publishing the libraries in a project is a little bit complicated and it will takes me a long time to tell you but a short introduce will help you

https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

this url does not have all the info but is a first step.

Comment: Angular CLI 1.74 (Angular 5) does not support ng g library as it starts on Angular > 6

Comment: Ok, I found you a essay about, basically explain all the files that you need to add manually (which generate with the cli command I post you and some more) to create your library https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e